# Why does mongo recommend a max scheduling priority of 30?

Tags: mongodb, performance, ulimit

Mongo has a list of recommended ulimit pages for production servers on their homepage [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/).  Most of these values make sense to me, but I'm curious why they recommend changing the scheduling priority (-e) to 30?

Can anyone give me an idea why lowering the max priority would benefit mongo?

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that the document is recommending changing the scheduling priority to 30. The preceding line states "You can use the ulimit command at the system prompt to check system limits, as in the following example". It appears that the 30 is a value found on whatever system this example was taken from.

The recommended settings are found at

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings.

Scheduling priority is not included in the recommended ulimit settings list.